# load the gif file as center of the Screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

1.What steps I will reproduce the problem?

2.I have  this  XML code for show the GIF file. as activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#000000">
     <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/loadingLayout"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:scrollbars="none" >
</RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

3. I have this code for show the gif file used extend the webview.

```
public class TestGifView  extends WebView
{
   public TestGifView(Context context, String path) {
       loadUrl(path);
        }
}
```

4.I have this code to access the TestGifView class in my Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TestGifView testGIF;
   RelativeLayout loadingLayout;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      testGIF=new TestGifView(this,"file:///android_asset/load.gif"); 
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // this for view as wrap content size.
      layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
       loadingLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.loadingLayout);
         loadingLayout.addView(testGIF,layoutParams);
```

5.I am getting output this 
      [image]

6. I should get out like this.
   [image]
   7.help me ,how to resolve this problem?

Comment: It's a `WebView`.  Where do you expect to center an image in the  `WebView` if not in the html/css in the `WebView` itself.

Comment: Also why are you adding a `WebView` just to display a gif? That's complete overkill. Why does it have to be a gif in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

First, Replace fill_parent with match_parent, as fill_parent is deprecated.
Second, remove the second RelativeLayout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#000000"
      android:id="@+id/loadingLayout">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

try with that first, if it doesn't work, then try Suhas B solution there

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I referred this link "http://androiddreamers.blogspot.in/2014/02/example-to-show-animated-gif-image-in.html" ,i got the correct output.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code in your `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I referred this link "androiddreamers.blogspot.in/2014/02/…;, and i tried ,got correct output.. thanks for your reply....

Answer (score -1):

It was an issue of WebView which not work with wrapContent.
I have on solution for this

Replace

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

with

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
```

Comment: if we set the layout  width ,height  size for all devices it will hide the stretched..

Comment: @RameshC you can use measure height width of screen and after that find center and put those values.

Comment: I referred this link "http://androiddreamers.blogspot.in/2014/02/example-to-show-animated-gif-image-in.html", and i tried ,got correct output.. thanks for  your reply....